# JQuery - remove special characters but allow other languages

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function that removes special characters

```
  title = title.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
```

The problem is, it also removes characters from other languages e.g. Arabic

How do i amend, so characters from other languages aren't removed?

Comment: Does this have anything specifically to do with jQ as suggested by title and tag?

Answer (score 0):

here `title.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` you are trying to keep all non-special characters, but there might be a lot of non-unicode characters, so may be we can go vice versa: remove most special characters like this

```
var r = title.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
```